# How To Rename File Extension Using Powershell Set-Content

Tags: powershell, csv, batch-processing, powershell-3.0, file-extension

I have the following Powershell code where I intend to scan a folder for new files that are dropped into as .TXT files, replace commas with | (the pipe symbol), remove double quotes from the file and rename the file from .TXT to .CSV and save it to an output folder.

```
param($InputDIR,$OutputDIR)

$Dir = get-childitem $InputDIR -Recurse

$CSVList = $Dir | where {$_.Name -like "*.TXT"}
Write-Host -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Blue "Scanning For Input Files In $InputDIR"
Foreach ($csvfile in $CSVList )
{
#ASSIGN THE CSV FILE INTO A VARIABLE.
$CSVFullFileName = $csvfile.FullName
$CSVFileName = $csvfile.Name
$InputFile = (Join-Path $InputDIR $CSVFileName)

Get-Content $InputFile | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ",", "|" } | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace """", "" } | Set-Content ($InputFile+".csv")

Write-Host -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Blue "Working on $CSVFileName"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Blue "Object Scan: $_"
#Remove-Item $InputFile
#Rename-Item ($InputFile+".csv") $InputFile
```

}

The issue I am stumped by is that the Set-Content outputs the file with the ".CSV" extension appended to the ".TXT" similar to as follows:  "myfile.TXT.CSV".

How could I do what I am trying to do and also output the new file as .CSV extension without the original .TXT extension?

Comment: your mean change extension ?! `ren myfile.txt myfile.txt.csv` or `Dir *.txt | rename-item -newname {  $_.name  -replace '\.txt$','.csv'  }`

Comment: The issue is that you are taking the original name and adding `.csv` onto the end of it. If you want to replace the extension you need to remove the extension from the original filename first.

Comment: `Dir *.txt | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace '\.txt$','.txt.csv' }` then i dir changed i .txt to .txt.csv :-?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
param($InputDIR,$OutputDIR)

$Dir = get-childitem $InputDIR -Recurse

$CSVList = $Dir | where {$_.Name -like "*.TXT"}
Write-Host -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Blue "Scanning For Input Files In $InputDIR"
Foreach ($csvfile in $CSVList )
{
#ASSIGN THE CSV FILE INTO A VARIABLE.
$CSVFullFileName = $csvfile.FullName
$CSVFileName = $csvfile.Name
$InputFile = (Join-Path $InputDIR $CSVFileName)
$newFileName = "{0}.csv" -f ([io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($CSVFileName))
$newFilePath = (Join-Path $InputDIR $newFileName)

Get-Content $InputFile | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ",", "|" } | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace """", "" } | Set-Content $newFilePath

Write-Host -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Blue "Working on $CSVFileName"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Blue "Object Scan: $_"
#Remove-Item $InputFile
#Rename-Item ($InputFile+".csv") $InputFile
```

I determine the new file Path using two steps:

1. Retrieve the file name without extension (using **[io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension**) and add ".csv" to it using a format string
2. Join the directory with the new filename

Comment: @EtanReisner this really helped me and by reposting my original code it helped me more because I know exactly where to place the additions in my code.

Comment: You can use `$csvfile.Basename` to get the same value as `[io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`

Comment: @motionpotion Saying "replace this/these lines .... with this/these lines ...." would also have told you where they needed to go. But the main thrust of my comment was that a random code blob is not generally helpful without any explanation (in this sort of context) which has since been fixed.

Comment: Since only files with the extension `.txt` are processed, it would suffice to define the output file like this: `$OutputFile = $InputFile -replace '\.txt$', '.csv'`